# How to increment value in a struct matrix in c?

Tags: c, matrix

I've calloc'd a correlation matrix in a struct but am unable to increment/set values in that matrix. The struct is

```
typedef struct matrixStruct{
    char** word;
    int numberOfWords;
    int** matrix;
} matrix;
```

This is how i've allocated the structure using calloc. I've used calloc because i'd like all the values in the matrix to be 0.

```
//Allocate rows of matrix
wordStore->matrix = calloc(2000,sizeof(int*));
//Allocate columns of matrix
for(int j = 0; j< 2000; j++)
{
    wordStore->matrix[j] = calloc(2000,sizeof(int*));
}
```

Assume i have an array which has values of

```
int reference [] = {20,400,5,1899};
```

And this is how i'm trying to assign/increment values within the matrix, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for(int k = 0; k<lenReference; k++)
{
    for(int l = 0; l<lenReference;l++)
    {

        wordStore->matrix[k][l] += 1;

        if(k == l){

            wordStore->matrix[k][l] = 0;

        }
    }

}
```

This is the print loop that i'm using, and when i run the file it has an error that says "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector", but i thought that this was the correct way to print a 2d array. What is the issue with this print?

```
for(int i = 0; i<2000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<2000; j++)
        {
            printf("%08d ", words.matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Aside: the second allocation `calloc(2000,sizeof(int*));` should not be for the pointer size but the `int` itself. `calloc(2000,sizeof(int));`. Also, you have not shown what `words` is where the compilation fails.

Comment: How are you declaring `wordStore` and `words`?

Comment: Yes, though `sizeof(int*)` is surely at least as large as `sizeof(int)`, so that's an efficiency and style problem, not an operational problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree that it's probably not causing the problem OP is seeing, but I certainly wouldn't dismiss it as an "efficiency and style problem".  It's a correctness problem, albeit one that is likely being masked.

Comment: re. `sizeof(int*)` vs `sizeof(int)`, a useful pattern to get the allocated size correct is `ptr = calloc(count, sizeof(*ptr))`, i.e., instead of repeating the type itself, use the dereferenced pointer variable. (In case of multiple levels of indirection, just add more dereferencing with additional `*` and/or `[]`.)

Comment: Without seeing the declarations, it's impossible to really debug this, but in the absence of an MCVE, it seems likely that `words` does not have type `matrix`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, as long as at least as much memory is allocated as is used, the program's behavior is well defined (or at least, not for this reason undefined).  This issue does not cause incorrect behavior, so it is not a correctness problem any more than if the OP hardcoded the size of an `int` in their implementation.  In fact, the OP's is probably *less* of an issue than a hardcoded size.  Their code is not *strictly conforming*, but that does not make it *incorrect*.

Comment: @TomKarzes words is declared as ```*upperCase wordsStore``` in the void function, and i didn't explicitly declare words as i thought that calloc would be declaring it. Do you think thats the isssue?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess we have different definitions of correct, acceptable code.  If someone is using the wrong data type in a `sizeof` expression, then I consider it incorrect and a bug, even if the type they are incorrectly using is larger than the correct type.

Comment: @WeatherVane i've made that change and it now is printing a large matrix with values of 0

Comment: @nutellasandwich Yes it's an issue.  `calloc` is a function call.  It doesn't declare things for you.

Comment: I could post the full program as a comment if that would help?

Comment: @nutellasandwich, no, we don't want the whole program, and you couldn't fit it in a comment anyway.  **Edit the question** to contain a **[mcve]** demonstrating the problem.